PHP Mail to Googlemail. All DNS Entries exist. Still no mail to googlemail
i added everything google mentioned. DKIM, DMARC and SPF. Still no luck. What am i missing? Is there something wrong with my entries?
My inital question:
PHP Mail to Googlemail. SPF only
DKIM:
Name: dkim._domainkey.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN
Value: "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=PUBLICKEYVALUE"
TTL: 3600

DMARC:
Name: _dmarc.DOMAIN
Value: "v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:emailadress"
TTL: 3600

SPF:
Name: SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN
Value: "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
TTL: 3600

Do i need to add anything to my email headers?

Send an email to https://www.mail-tester.com, and check what that has to say afterwards.

@Jules can you paste your code here which you are using for mail

Ok now i know that i need to add a header to mail(). But i cannot find how the header for dkim looks like except for using phpMailer. I'm not using it.
How do the headers look like for simple mail()?

A mail header is a header, no matter what software you use to create the email. The mailserver still expects the same info in the same format. Paste the PHPMailer-based example you've found into your question, then we can see what you mean. Using it with mail() should simply be a syntax change in how you build the header string in PHP

P.S. I would though, strongly recommend switching to PHPMailer. It's much more reliable at building emails correctly, and without you needing to understand all the fiddly header syntax and so on. You just give it some clean, structured info about what the mail should contain, and it does all the hard work for you. And it's troubleshooting / debugging mode is really helpful too

I seriously doubt that the headers looke the same for mail() and phpMailer.
$mail->DKIM_domain = ‘yourdomain.com’;
$mail->DKIM_private = dirname(FILE).’/key.private’; // Make sure to protect the key from being publicly accessible!
$mail->DKIM_selector = ‘YOUR-SELECTOR’;
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = ‘YOUR-PASSWORD’;
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;

@ADyson I'm not using phpMailer. Too much overhead for this change. I'm using simple mail().

I just need an example for mail(). Thats all. Who knows the mail() headers for a dkim?

[edit] your question to include code, don't hide it, unformatted, down here in the comments

I seriously doubt that...of course they do. PHPMailer has just written some code which takes in the necessary info in a neatly structured, usable format and turns it into a raw DKIM header signature which it then sends in the email. If you want to do that without using PHPMailer (or any other library with a similar feature) you'll have to write that for yourself, or at the very least, hard-code it into your header string. Examples of a a raw DKIM signature header can be found online, e.g. in places like https://knowledge.validity.com/s/articles/DKIM-signature-header-detail?language=en_US

Too much overhead for this change...really? It'll save you time now, and in the long-run, by making it so that you don't have to keep re-inventing the wheel for stuff like DKIM, or sending attachments, or other fiddly bits and pieces. And the basic setup to send a mail could hardly be considered complex or time-consuming to create. Honestly I switched to it quite a few years ago, and email-related life in PHP is now 100 times easier...

... it's the equivalent of driving a nice car, vs building your own primitive bike from old pieces of wood you found in your yard

@ADyson There is a giant difference. DKIM_domain and the real headers. That's what i meant. And no i'm not using phpMailer.

BTW what service provider are you using to send your mail via? I'm a bit surprised, if they're registered for DKIM, that they don't attach this to their outgoing mail automatically for you.

The Hoster Hetzner

There is a giant difference...yes, and I've just explained why, and that the underlying structure is the same, and what you'd need to do about it if you don't want to use the ready-made tool for the job. And no i'm not using phpMailer...I know, you already said that. My point was that your life would be a lot easier if you did

Ok. So you did all this setup then I assume: https://docs.hetzner.com/konsoleh/account-management/email/mailsecurity/ ? . And I assume your mail() code sends via their systems? Are you sure it doesn't auto-attach the DKIM already? What was the result / recommendation when you sent a test email to https://www.mail-tester.com/?

I may be missing something but email security measures like SPF, DKIM, DMARC... are not implemented by the email client. They are implemented by the email server, often with the help of some DNS records. Client is only required to authenticate and (often) to encrypt connection, and only when using SMTP (local mail servers already know who you are). Last time I checked, mail() didn't support any of this. I've recently switched hosting and mail providers and I spent a few days fiddling with TXT records and other settings in my provider control panel.

@ADyson i cannot use this because of the hosting packet. It is not available. And no it makes no sense to introduce the phpmailer for this. I'd have to know the smpt credentials for that and it just costs unnecessary time to change it.
I'd appreaciate it if you could acceppt that and not bring it up again. No to PhpMailer.

@ÁlvaroGonzález it is both. Because my mail Server is not adding the DKIM header automatically i have to do that before mailing.

Still weird to me. If the mail Server checks the dkim and spf entries on the sender Server. Why do we need to add any headers except from? It should be enough to look up all needed dns entries. Just more work for devs.

I'd have to know the smpt credential...no you wouldn't. PHPMailer can be configured to forward the email it builds on via mail() or the local sendmail. SMTP is not required - it's one of the options you can set to make SMTP true or false in the PHPMailer settings.

Seriously, read https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer?tab=readme-ov-file#why-you-might-need-it if you don't believe me. And then the example, found in the PHPMailer docs, which shows you how to send using mail() under the hood. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps . Not sure where you got the idea from that PHPMailer requires SMTP.

If the mail Server checks the dkim and spf entries on the sender Server...yeah, it validates the contents of the email it's just reeived against the entries on the sending server, in order to validate that the email actually came from the server it claims to. It's a bit like the way SSL certificates help to prove that you're actually visiting the website you appear to be visiting.

Again If the mail Server checks the dkim and spf entries on the sender Server, then a additional header is not needed. From is the only header that is needed if the server is able to check the dns entries. The only reason for the additional headers is if the server can't access the dns entries and has to rely on the headers. But as far as i can see, it can access the dns entries.. so it is not necessary. Seems like an arbitrary rule to me. "It just is"

There's quite a good explanation of how it works here: https://www.proofpoint.com/uk/threat-reference/dkim . As you can see the signature is required to be sent in the email so that the receiving server can compare it to the hash it gets from following the  same process itself, and then verifying that against's the sending server's public key. It wouldn't work if that comparison wasn't available. That's why you need the header in the email, containing the encrypted signature generated by the sending server. This proves the email hasn't been tampered with in transit.

I'm not really sure why you think you know better than the security experts and implementers of this technology. You claim it's not needed based purely on your own misunderstanding of the process. I do not claim to be an expert in this stuff either but with a bit of time spending reading up on it, it's not hard to get enough information to understand why the process works as it does.

For anyone having similar problems, I got it to work, finally.
It did not work because of a few things:

You might need to add your IP address to the SPF DNS record.
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:YOUR-IP ~all

Your private key needs to be created like this (not with aes128):
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:YOURPASS -out dkim_rsa.private 2048
openssl rsa -in dkim_rsa.private -out dkim_rsa.public -pubout -outform PEM


